# Output a percentage of matrices of different sizes in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am creating a function that takes matrixes of different sizes and converts the number of the total points scored into a percentage. I feel like I am missing a simple step that would complete this.

```
function weight = calculatepercentage(exams, homework, quizzes);

exams = ([60,60]./60);
homework = ([30,30,30]./30);
quizzes = ([10,10,10,10]./10);

eScore = exams*.60;
hScore = homework*.25;
qScore = quizzes*.15;

disp(eScore + hScore + qScore)

end
```

Comment: welcome! the code does not match your description. You are handing in ones (you could have also just `ones` to create the vectors...) and you are multiplying them with a number, which is smaller than 1 (with no relation to the total points). The most important question is, if you want to have the percentage of the total numbers (all scored numbers of all exams) or if it is the percentage of the maximum storable number (which is unknown and must be provided as input).

Comment: Your function takes in three matrices as input values, but then overwrites them. So it will always produce the same output. Next, you have arrays of different sizes that you try to add together, but this will fail. Not sure what your intention there is. It would help if you give example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that is probably doing the job. Your function was overwriting the variables that you hand over to the function.

```
final_score = calculatepercentage([60], [30 28], [5 5 5]);

function weight = calculatepercentage(exams, homework, quizzes)

% maximum points that can be obtained in each category
exam_maxpoints = 60;
homework_maxpoints = 30;
quizzes_maxpoints = 10;

% calc percentage per category
exams_percent = mean(exams./exam_maxpoints);
homework_percent = mean(homework./homework_maxpoints);
quizzes_percent = mean(quizzes./quizzes_maxpoints);

% calc percentage by weights for each category
eScore = exams_percent*.60;
hScore = homework_percent*.25;
qScore = quizzes_percent*.15;

% get final percentage
weight = eScore + hScore + qScore;
disp(weight)

end
```